# sum the count duplicated in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I try to sum the duplicated rows. But I get the KeyError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkdup.py", line 9, in <module>
    dups_data = df.duplicated(subset=['VIP_ID_SOURCE'], keep = False).sum()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4381, in duplicated
    raise KeyError(diff)
KeyError: Index([u'VIP_ID_SOURCE'], dtype='object')
```

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
  
# making data frame from csv file
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter='|', header=None)
# print(data)


dups_data = df.duplicated(subset=['VIP_ID_SOURCE'], keep = False).sum()
print(dups_data)
```

This is the sample csv file:

```
VIP_ID|SYSTEM_CODE|VIP_CODE|VIP_ID_SOURCE|GENDER|TIER|ACTIVE_MEMBER|EMAIL_ADDRESS|VIP_CENTER_CODE|TELEPHONE
826914|QQ|123321123as|F08210020322|M|AD|1||1234|28386078
798089|QQ|123321123as|F08210020322|M|AD|1||1234|73848487
798087|QQ|123321123as|F08210020905|F|AD|1||1234|30608803
796490|QQ|123321123as|F08210020403|M|AD|1||1234|38581312
```

Comment: There is problem `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter='|', header=None)` - `header=None` generate `0,1,2` columns. It is used if csv has no header. So soluion is use `pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter='|')`

Comment: I found the answer.  ```dups_data = df.reset_index.duplicated(subset=[3], keep = False).sum()```  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dups_data = df.reset_index.duplicated(subset=[3], keep = False).sum()